# Turning whole <li> into links

Tags: html, css

There is a lot of these around but I cant find a way to do it without messing up the menu itself.

So I was messing about and came up with a menu I rather liked so I would like to keep it, as I was only messing about and seeing what I could come up with I didn't think about it and make the links.

Anything I try now seems to mess up the `display: inline-block;`.

### HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="item1"><span>Home</span><div></div>
        </li
        ><li class="item2"><span>About</span><div></div>

        </li
        ><li class="item3"><span>Games</span><div></div>

        </li
        ><li class="item4"><span>Data</span><div></div>

        </li
        ><li class="item5"><span>Films</span><div></div>

        </li
        ><li class="item6"><span>Contact</span><div></div>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
#menu {
    margin-top: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 200px;
    min-width: 975px;
    position: relative;
}
ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
}
li {
    width: 150px;
    height: 160px;
    display: inline-block;
    transition:height 1s;
}
li:hover {
    height: 190px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
li span {
}
a {
    display:block;
}
.item1 {
    background: #00CC99;
}
.item1 div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    background: url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ecqlipse2/HOME.png) no-repeat bottom;
}
.item2 {
    background: #006699;
}
.item2 div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    background: url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ecqlipse2/BOOK.png) no-repeat bottom;
}
.item3 {
    background: #0066CC;
}
.item3 div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    background: url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ecqlipse2/COUNTERSTRIKE.png) no-repeat bottom;
}
.item4 {
    background: #0066FF;
}
.item4 div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    background: url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ecqlipse2/NETWORK%20-%20HDD.png) no-repeat bottom;
}
.item5 {
    background: #6666FF;
}
.item5 div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    background: url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ecqlipse2/FILE%20-%20MOVIE.png) no-repeat bottom;
}
.item6 {
    background: #CC33FF;
}
.item6 div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    background: url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ecqlipse2/PHONE.png) no-repeat bottom;
}
```

Sorry to include a large amount of CSS but I found the different ways I have tried tend to break all kinds of different things.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/AtBQw/)

**Stuff I have tried:**

I have tried to put `a` inside `height: 100%; width: 100%;` and put it on top using `z-index` then hiding it but this does not seem to work.

Playing `a` around each of the `<li>` as I had no idea how it would react, this also seemed to fail. If I get the "display: block;" it would work but mess the menu up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are trying to make link of every block? Why not put the stuff that represents the block into a anchor?

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="item1">
            <a href="test">
                <span>Home</span>
                <div></div>
            </a>
            ...
```

Where you just set the height of the anchor to 100%:

```
#menu a
{
    height: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zsrTx/)

*Note that i only did this with the home button*

Comment: Because I'm stupid... Haha, Iv been coding all day and my brains just stopped working... Thanks you.

Comment: @Ruddy hehe, i know the feeling ^^ Glad i could help!

Comment: Any chance you know of a way to get rid of the spaces that the `inline-block` causes? I put the HTML like it is to stop it and I know you can use `font-size: 0;` or something but is there any better way?

Comment: @Ruddy you can use a float to get rid of the white-space; [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zsrTx/3/) If you're not satisfied with that you can use some of trick discribed **[here](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)**

Comment: How can I then center it if it is floating? Never mind I done it. I was just being lazy and didnt want to try haha.

Comment: @Ruddy you can still use `<ul>` or your `<div #menu>` to position your menu. I do not know the scenario you're in, but you can also use the font trick you described to get the same effect: http://jsfiddle.net/zsrTx/6/

Answer (score 0):

without messing around too much with your code, you could get rid of those empty `div` if you don't have any other plans for them. To keep the html structure correct and valid the `a` element should go inside the `li`, not outside. Then changing the html to:

```
<li class="item1"><a><span>Home</span></a>
```

and the CSS:

```
.item1 {
background: #00CC99 url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ecqlipse2/HOME.png) no-repeat bottom;
}
```

Should solve it without breaking your design.

**demo:**(first `li` only) http://jsfiddle.net/Xf96N/